# How to create a subtle enlarge when mouseover on actionLink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a subtle expand & contract effect when I hover over on the `Details`, `Edit`, and `Delete` links on the web app. With the code I have, it is not doing anything. I think I don't have the right selector.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) 
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            { 
                @:|
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID })@: |

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID }) 
            }
        </td>
    </tr>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#item').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).animate({ height: '+=25', width: '+=25' })
                   .animate({ height: '-=25', width: '-=25' });           
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am very new into jQuery, so I am not sure if I can have this kind of effect on things other than images.

Comment: You need to show us the rendered HTML, not the loop code. Also, you most likely don't need to use jQuery for what you're asking - you can use CSS transforms.

Comment: sorry, what is the rendered HTML? My **Layout.cshtml**? For my assignment, I need to use some sort of jQuery functions.

Comment: The selector you're using targets an id (`#`). Your use case makes me think you should use classes to target the elements (`.`)

Comment: Do I have to create new class definition with the id ? `('.item')` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I happen to believe the goal of your current assignment is to give you the opportunity to learn how to use existing documentation properly. What your question does is declare: *"I don't know how to use jQuery's documentation, can someone else please do it for me?"* If we do what you're supposed to do for you, you won't learn what you're supposed to learn. (Which is how to find answers on your own, without any help). jQuery is one of the best documented libraries out there. If you can't handle jQuery, you'll have a lot of trouble with everything else.

Comment: Sorry, if my question is misinterpreted, but I certainly do not want my question to be answered for me. I just wanted some assistance. Perhaps, I needed to phrase my question better, but nevertheless, thank you for your kind information.

Comment: No problem. I want to ask you, is the `$(this).animate(...)` part something you have written?

Comment: @StraightUp Rendered HTML is what it looks like when you view source on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you have written this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#item').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: '+=25', width: '+=25' })
               .animate({ height: '-=25', width: '-=25' });           
    });
 });
```

... parts of it are good.

But let's look at what's not so good:

**1. You shouldn't animate `height` and `width`...**

... because they will affect everything that's following your elements in `DOM`, causing them to reposition.

When you animate anything that will affect the position of element in `DOM` it will also affect everything else that is following it in `DOM`. As an alternative, you can use a set of `CSS` attributes that only affect the element rendering without affecting it's position in content flow. These are:

- `left`, `right`, `top` & `bottom` combined with any `position` value other than `static` ( typically `relative`)
- `transform` - this gives you a full range of `2d` and `3d` transformations but they only happen on the image of the element (its render) not on the element itself - the element remains untouched, occupying the same amount of space in content flow.

In your case, the best practice is to use `transform` typically with a value of `scale(1.05)`. However, using `jQuery`'s animate is not considered best practice, as applying this effect using pure `CSS` is less expensive for most browsers/devices and will most likely result in a better user experience.

**2.** [`.mouseover()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) will apply the transformation when you hover the item but you also need to specify the return animation, using `.mouseout()`. Typically, you want to use [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), which is a shorthand for both: `.hover(function_in, function_out)`

Example:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#item').hover(
       function () { $(this).animate({ transform: 'scale(1.05)'}); }, 
       function () { $(this).animate({ transform: 'scale(1)'}); }
     );
 });
```

---

**3.** You seem to want to perform two animations, using

```
$(this).animate({ ... })
       .animate({ ... });
```

If you want to chain jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) calls, you need to do it using the callback function parameter (which should always be last - 2nd or 3rd param), like this

```
 $(this).animate(
   {...first animation...}, 
   function(){
     $(this).animate(
       {...second animation... }
     );
   }
 );
```

But, as a general rule, try to stay away from `.animate()`. If you must use it, limit its use to `transition` or `opacity`. Where possible, replace it with `.velocity()` - it's a jquery plugin, also available as standalone.
Where possible, use `CSS` animations, or [`WA-API`](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info.